# Call environment (native) specific global javascript functions in Angular 2

Tags: angular, native, angular-cli

I'm developing a web application in Angular 2 (via the `angular-cli`) which can be loaded in a native mobile app (on iOS and Android) via a simple URL.

It is possible to interact with the native app using *bridge functions*. These functions are added to the global scope in the app's web browser (and thus do not exist in a normal web browser). An example of such a function is `echoNative()` which returns information about the native platform:

```
{
  "platform": "iOS",
  "message": "Native received Echo call"
}
```

In a normal javascript application (without angular), it is possible to include these functions in your javascript code without the `angular-cli` throwing errors.

I have the following questions:

1. How can I prevent the `angular-cli` from failing to build my application when I use these functions?
2. Is it possible to write a *mock library* for these functions which loads the functions if they exist on the global scope and provides a replacement if they don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should find/write yourself type definitions for these functions. See more information about declarations files in [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html). The simplest example would be something like creating following file:

   ```
   // src/app/index.d.ts

   declare interface Window {
     // This will tell TypeScript, that such function exists on `window`, but won't provide implementation for it. So if there is no implementation somewhere else, TypeScript won't error, but it will fail in runtime.
     echoNative: () => { platform: string, message: string }; 
   }
   ```
2. Yes, you can do it same way, as you would do in JS (don't forget to import this file from your application, so it's included in the bundle):

   ```
   // src/app/mocks.ts

   if (typeof window.echoNative === 'undefined') {
     window.echoNative = () => {
       // Your mock implementation here.
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What imports do I need to do in my components so they know this declaration and this mock?

Comment: First item should be included automatically if it's inside `src/` folder. Another options is to add it to `"files"` array in `tsconfig.json`. Second one should be included as a normal import (better include in every file, which uses these functions, but also possible to do it in `main.ts` for example): `import './path-to-mocks/mocks.ts';`.